# javascript asynchronous forEach loop

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to run elasticsearch on an array of values(indices) and I ran into javaScript async trouble:

```
function(indices) {
  let results = [];

  indices.forEach(d => ESClient.search({
      index: d.indexName,
      body: {
        query: {
          match: {
            first_name: 'fred'
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .then(resp => results.push(resp))
  )
}
```

There should be three elems in indices, how should I go about returning results with all three responds from my search?

Comment: There's a better way, using [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-msearch) you can send all your queries in one single request and get the responses in the same order ;-)

Comment: @Val Nice, but for some reason it's now giving me a parsing error saying first_name doesn't exist. But I'm sure it does since it does give me the result before, just not pushing in the right order

Comment: That's a different issue, I guess. My advice was simply to use a multi-search instead of tinkering with asynch JS.

Comment: I figured it out! The docs says to use match_all but it works with match. Thanks for the advice!!

Comment: And if you're sending the exact same query to several indexes, another much better way is to simply [use an alias that spans all indexes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) and send a single query to that alias.

Answer (score 0):

In you case you could use `map` and `Promise.all`. You the map creates an array of Promises for those indices, the `Promise.all` waits until those Promises are resolved and returns an array with their resolved values.

```
function(indices) {
  let results = Promise.all(indices.map(d => ESClient.search({
    index: d.indexName,
    body: {
      query: {
        match: {
          first_name: 'fred'
        }
      }
    }
  })))
}
```

But that's not that readable so I would move the mapping callback to an own function:

```
function searchForIndex(d) {
  return ESClient.search({
    index: d.indexName,
    body: {
      query: {
        match: {
          first_name: 'fred'
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

function(indices) {
  let results = Promise.all(indices.map(searchForIndex))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
search(indices) {
  return Promise.all(
    indices.map((d) => {
      return ESClient.search(yourElasticSearchPayload)
    })
  );
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

this.search(indices).then((results) => {
  // do something with results
}).catch((reason) => { 
  // failure-reason of the first failed request
  console.log(reason);
});
```